# How to update LINQ class before insert

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am attempting to access an autogenerated primary key using LINQ/SQL during an insert. I need to use that value in the class' Name attribute:

```
Incident inc = new Incident
{
    StartDateTime = DateTime.Now
};

Model.db.Incidents.InsertOnSubmit(inc);
inc.Name = "Incident #" + inc.ID;

try
{
    Model.db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    Model.db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I am probably going about this the wrong way. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: The object doesn't generate the key, the database does.  The object doesn't have the key until the insert is performed.  Ideally it shouldn't be *needed* in another field.  The ID value can be included in the display when showing the record, it shouldn't be needed for setting a value when inserting the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is probably a time where a stored procedure (still usable in Linq) may be a good fit.**

So, I'll outline 2 ways to handle this: One will be a bit more work but better performance, and the second just modifies your code to make it work as is.

**Why your code doesn't work:**
The reason being, you cannot get the ID before you make the insert - it doesn't exist yet.

So, in Linq, you'd need to

> 1. Insert new record
> 2. Update the Name to include the generated ID
> 3. Save again

This will cause 2 full round trips to database;

---

To avoid 2 round trips to the database, you can create a simple stored proc in SQL, and drag it into your Linq classes where it will become available as a method.

Inside the stored proc, you'd insert the new record and then immediately update the name using the generated id:

Pseudo-code:

```
Create Procedure dbo.Incident_InsertAndUpdateName
@ ... [ your entity vars ]
As 
  Begin
   Insert Into [ table ]
   Select @[your list of vars]

   Declare @NewID int
   Set @NewID = Select @@Identity

   Update [ table ]
   Set Name = "Incident #" + Convert(Varchar(10), @NewID)
   Where ID = @NewID
 End
```

Then, in Linq, once you get the stored procedure into the DBML classes, you'd just call

```
// by dragging the Stored Proc from designer onto your Incident table, 
// LINQ will generate a mapping from the stored procedure to the Incidents entity 
// such that you don't have to map the fields yourself
Model.db.Incident_InsertAndUpdateName(inc);
```

**That's the performant way; to modify your code, you'd do this:**

```
    Incident inc = new Incident
    {
        StartDateTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    Model.db.Incidents.InsertOnSubmit(inc);
    try
    {
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
        inc.Name = "Incident #" + inc.ID;
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I figured that making two trips for one insert would not be ideal. The stored proc is working perfectly, thanks again.

Comment: Also, without using explicit transactions, using 2 calls to SubmitChanges() would make it possible to have inconsistent data (e.g. if the second SubmitChanges fails the name value will be incorrect).

Comment: I think there's a way to have Linq auto-sync the "Name" column, after the insert, isn't there?  That would avoid the duplicated logic in the DB + in the code.

Comment: There is no duplicated logic in my example. Just a stored proc call from Linq with all logic in the proc... but if you find the example post it :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a double-submit, because the auto-generated ID won't be set until the "insert" command has been sent to the database.

```
    Incident inc = new Incident
    {
        StartDateTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    Model.db.Incidents.InsertOnSubmit(inc);
    inc.Name = "Incident #" + inc.ID;
    try
    {
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
        inc.Name = "Incident #" + inc.ID;
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Obviously two round-trips to the database is not optimal.  I'd consider setting up a stored procedure that will use "scope_identity" to set the "Name" column immediately on insert.  Or, even better, set up a database trigger that will do the job -- this way won't require any coding changes, and you can continue to use the Linq insert.

Answer (score 2):

Id is given at the Db level, so you have to save it first;

```
Incident inc = new Incident
    {
        StartDateTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    Model.db.Incidents.InsertOnSubmit(inc);

    try
    {
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
        inc.Name = "Incident #" + inc.ID;
        Model.db.SubmitChanges()
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Model.db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```